# I am not getting any output from the provided partitioning algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, partitioning, partition, data-partitioning

The given program below is supposed to randomly pick an element from the list i.e `piv`  and return the list in which all the elements smaller than `piv` are on the left side and larger elements are on the right side of the `piv` in the list . But I am getting no output, just blank screen.

sample `INPUT:[7,9,4,8,3,6,2,5]`

if piv=8 one of the possible outputs `OUTPUT:[4,3,2,7,6,5,8,9]`

```py
import random
def swap(arr,a,b):
    arr[a],arr[b]=arr[b],arr[a]
    return arr
def partition(arr,n):
    piv=random.choice(arr)
    j=(n-1)
    i=0
    while(i<j):
        if(arr[i]<piv and arr[j]<piv):
            i+=1
        elif(arr[i]>piv and arr[j]>piv):
            j-=1
        elif(arr[i]>piv and arr[j]<piv):
            swap(arr,i,j)
            j-=1
            i+=1
        elif(arr[i]<piv and arr[j]>piv):
            j-=1
            i+=1
    return arr
z=[7,9,4,8,3,6,2,5]
y=partition(z,8)
print(y)
```

Comment: Have you considered an infinite loop? Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Your code goes into an infinite loop since your `if`s never consider that, for example, `arr[i] == piv`. The code `'drops off the end'` of the `if/elif` chain choosing none of them leaving `i` and `j` unchanged.

Comment: I did put <= condition put even after that its not giving a partitioned list . The elements are just randomly jumbled not in desired manner i.e smaller elements on left of piv and larger on right.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add some greater than or equal signs, since the algorithm doesn't take into account that piv and the value can be the same.

```
import random


def swap(arr, a, b):
    arr[a], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[a]
    return arr


def partition(arr, n):
    piv = random.choice(arr)
    print(piv)
    j = (n-1)
    i = 0
    while(i < j):
        if(arr[i] < piv and arr[j] < piv):
            i += 1
        elif(arr[i] > piv and arr[j] > piv):
            j -= 1
        elif(arr[i] >= piv and arr[j] <= piv):
            swap(arr, i, j)
            j -= 1
            i += 1
        elif(arr[i] <= piv and arr[j] >= piv):
            j -= 1
            i += 1
    return arr


z = [7, 9, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5]
y = partition(z, 8)
print(y)
```

Comment: I did try to run it but it isn't working.  The output isn't partitioned around the piv.

Comment: Did you copy my provided solution? Because that works for me.

Comment: Yes i exactly copy pasted it and for some cases it is and for some it just gives a jumbled list.

Comment: Is there any way i can show you the screenshot

Comment: 5,9 and many more . Aslo in some instances it will show right output but after some more trials it will again give wrong output for the same piv.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def swap(arr,a,b):
    arr[a],arr[b]=arr[b],arr[a]
    return arr

def partition(arr,n):
    piv=random.randint(0,len(arr)-1)#randomly chooses an integer to be pivot
    print(arr)
    #print(piv, arr[piv])
    print("The partition is being done around element :" , arr[piv])
    #print(arr)
    arr[len(arr)-1],arr[piv] = arr[piv],arr[len(arr)-1]#swaps pivot with last element 
    #print(arr)#updated array 
    i = -1
    j = 0
    pivot = arr[len(arr)-1]
    for j in range(len(arr)):
    
        if(arr[j] < pivot):
            i += 1
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
    arr[i+1],arr[len(arr)-1] = arr[len(arr)-1],arr[i+1]
    return arr
z=[7,9,4,8,3,6,2,5]
y=partition(z,8)
print(y)
```